# How to retrieve this value inside an array CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

[image: array]

For example, if I select a MemberSession id that is 1183, how can I then retrieve the value of Count?

I've been trying for the past couple of hours but I'm really confused.

Comment: If you would have spend these hours on reading the documentation and API documentation you would have learned a lot more than just finding the solution for your problem. Hint: Check the SessionHelper API.

Comment: I don't think it relates to the SessionHelper. It's just what my variables are called because I'm referring to the member's exercise sessions. Not the actual CakePHP Session. Sorry for the confusion.

http://i.gyazo.com/2f9221ac0ca9f72a12f81d5c2adda8e9.png